# Weird .NET PATH Error

Tags: c#, php, .net, path

I'm trying to run a .NET Application built in Debug mode via PHP.

PHP runs other applications successfully.

The problem is when I run this application via Windows Explorer (i.e. by typing "C:\app.exe arguments" in the address bar), it works absolutely fine.

But, when I run the same with EITHER PHP or CMD.exe (Command Prompt), the application crashes.
I looked at the generated metadata file in temp folder(s) and it had a FileNotFound IO Exception.

Any clues?

Looks like some notorious directory problem (working path, etc.)

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Comment: It's a huge code so I don't think it's a good idea to post.

Comment: Can you give us some clues to the environment you doing this in? ie version of OS, version PHP, etc

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like some notorious directory problem

Yes it sounds like an application bug - probably the application is making assumptions about the current working directory which aren't always true.  Possibly it's assuming the current working directory (`Environment.CurrentDirectory`) is the same as the application's installation directory (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`).

This assumption will probably be true when running the app from Windows explorer, but not necessarily in the general case.

To access files stored in a folder relative to the install directory, replace `Environment.CurrentDirectory` by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for getting back!!! I tried replacing AppDomain.Current... with Environment.CurrentDirectory, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Carlos, FileNotFoundException has a property FileName which normally contains the name of the file that was not found.  Once you see this, the penny will probably drop!  NB you may also have code that uses a relative path to open a file - this will be relative to the current working directory, and may also need to be changed to a full path relative to the application installation directory: `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)`.

Comment: Hi, I made the code to not open any files and the problem persisted. Later, I saw the file name you're talking about was a dll file. Now, that's even weirder - not only the dll files are present in the same directory as the application, but their folder is also included in the System's PATH variable. Thanks for your answer, though. [ Config: Windows 7 Home Premium, PHP 5+ -> XAMPP ]

Comment: @Carlos, you should post the full exception details if you want more help.  Maybe it's failing to load a .NET Assembly.  Note that the system PATH environment variable is not searched for .NET assemblies.

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVED:

I figured by a simple try-catch block that File Not Found was occurring because the current directory was same as cmd.exe's directory, i.e. C:\Users\MyUserName

To PHP Script, I simply added cd\ and now my working directory's same as where application (exe) is located.

It works! :)

Thanks for all the help! <3